# Identify records that has at least one unmatched given 3 datasets

Tags: python

I have 3 datasets and I would like to know which ID has at least one unmatched when comparing Dataset A, Dataset B and Dataset C. May I know how could I achieve this in Python?

```
Dataset A
ID Salary 
12 12,000
14 13,004
16 1,400
17 500
19 900
20 12,000
```

```
Dataset B
ID Name 
13 John 
12 James
15 Jacob
19 Michael
20 Seth
```

```
Dataset C
ID State
16 WA
17 WA
15 VC
19 NSW
20 WA
```

Comment: Show your own effort as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: Extract `ID` column from each dataframe and use `sets` predicates to find the difference

Comment: Try: `set(df1['ID']).symmetric_difference(df2['ID']).symmetric_difference(df3['ID'])` Answer: `{13, 14, 19, 20}`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Python I assumed you are using Pandas for the DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd
DatasetA = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[12,14,16,17,19,20],"Salary":[12000,13004,1400,500,900,12000]})
DatasetB = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[13,12,15,19,20],"Name":["John","James","Jacob","Michael","Seth"]})
DatasetC = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[16,17,15,19,20],"State":["WA","WA","VC","NSW","WA"]})
IDs_A = set(DatasetA["ID"])
IDs_B = set(DatasetB["ID"])
IDs_C = set(DatasetC["ID"])
AB = IDs_A.symmetric_difference(IDs_B)
BC = IDs_B.symmetric_difference(IDs_C)
AC = IDs_A.symmetric_difference(IDs_C)
result = AB.union(BC).union(AC)
print(result)
```